# How to get value of REG_DWORD variable from registry

Tags: python, python-3.x, winreg

I've created a variable in the Windows registry (via regedit), and want to get the value of my variable which has a `REG_DWORD` type.  I use this code to get the value:

```
def get_DWORD_val(): 
    from winreg import ConnectRegistry, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, OpenKey, QueryValue, REG_EXPAND_SZ, REG_SZ
    try:
           root = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
           print("---1")
           root_key = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Python', 0, KEY_READ)
           print("---2")
           [Pathname,regtype]=(QueryValue(root_key,"Ver_Tokenlog"))

    except WindowsError:
        return ["Error"]

    return Pathname
```

**Output :**

```
---1
---2
['Error']
```

This error is thrown:

```
winerror 2 the system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Whats the error ?

Comment: it can't return the Pathname.

Comment: the error is : winerror 2 the system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you meant QueryValueEx:

```
def get_DWORD_val(): 
    from winreg import ConnectRegistry, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, OpenKey, QueryValueEx, QueryValue, REG_EXPAND_SZ, REG_SZ, KEY_READ

    root = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
    print("---1")
    root_key = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Python', 0, KEY_READ)
    print("---2")
    Pathname,regtype = QueryValueEx(root_key, "Ver_Tokenlog")
    print(Pathname)
    print(regtype)


get_DWORD_val()
```

Output is:

```
---1
---2
256
4
```

Reg values:
[image]